# How to set transparent background for all bootstrap panels' bodies in my webapplication

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I add style section like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0);">
```

to my panel the background of the body is transparent. But I don't want to do copy-paste for every panel inside my application. I want them all to have transparent background.

I have tried to edit bootstrap.css in my project. I tried about 15 different places to put: `background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0);`  none of them worked.

This is my `bootstrap.css` file: http://wklej.org/hash/754afd00cfa/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe solution is to override Bootstrap's CSS in separated file, named for example `application.css`:

```
.panel.panel-primary{
    background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0);
}
```

You need to include this after `bootstrap.css`

Comment: Beautiful, simple solution. Thank you for this post.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend editing the bootstrap.css file directly. You can generate a custom bootstrap.css file along with a minified version at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. For any components you want transparent, enter in 'transparent' for their background color. For what you're describing, you'll want to change the @panel-bg variable under Panels.